# Addition of Long values inconsistent results

Tags: java, android, long-integer, addition, chronometer

I have developed an application that has 3 chronometers which are used like stopwatches. When the 3rd one is stopped, a `total` will be given which seems very simple and basic.

I have 3 test devices which I am testing to ensure that the app behaves as expected before going into production.

**Example:**

```
timeSetup = 00:00:05; 
timeProcessing = 00:00:10;
timeReconciliation = 00:00:05;
total = 00:00:20;
```

This is how I would expect it to run and on my personal device which is a Samsung Galaxy s7 which is API 26 this works perfectly.

However, on the other devices which are API 25 and API 22, the results come out at random such as `00:00:47` and `00:00:45` for the example above.

**Code:**

```
   Long total = timeSetup + timeProcessing + timeReconciliation;
                    int h = (int) (total / 3600000);
                    int m = (int) (total - h * 3600000) / 60000;
                    int s = (int) (total - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
                    totaltime = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s);
```

The code above is how I calculate the `total`.

Is there a more accurate or consistent way of adding 3 long values together or what is the reason for the inconsistencies between devices?

**Example code of how a time is calculated using chronometer:**

```
 chronometerReconciliation.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometerChanged) {
            chronometerReconciliation = chronometerChanged;
            timeReconciliation = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometerReconciliation.getBase();
            int h = (int) (timeReconciliation / 3600000);
            int m = (int) (timeReconciliation - h * 3600000) / 60000;
            int s = (int) (timeReconciliation - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
            timeShownReconciliation = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s);
            chronometerReconciliation.setText(timeShownReconciliation);
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: The primitiv types are not very precise and your operations are exceeding the precision boundaries, which leads to the inconsistant values. Use BigDecimal for high precision calculations.

Comment: Note that: dateFormat.format(c.getTime()); will return the local time of the device and not the one you calculating. Else, create the calendars from the time you have, subtract it and format only the output of minutes,hours and seconds

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos The c.getTime() is not used in the calculation, I am just getting the date so that I can send it through to a database as a date/time.

Comment: @Korashen so simply change the long's to BigDecimals?

Comment: Alright, anyway, use a Calendar instance of the total time, you can use the methods add(Calendar.MINUTES, -15) and so and format just the output

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Im not too familiar with how to use that. can you edit my code maybe to advise? would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Using BigDecimal is just an additional hint. It will help with precision. If it would solve the issue? Don't know, maybe, maybe not. I can't test it right now. Hence the comment and not as an answer.

Comment: okay @Korashen, appreciate the advice!